# WCF - Sample Chat PeerChannel - peers on different networks get different mesh?

Tags: wcf, networking, chat, sample

I have implemented the WCF ChatApp sample (Samples\WCFWFCardSpace\WCF\Scenario\PeerChannel\Chat), I got it working fine on my machine.

I put the CustomResolverService onto a real server and, again, everything works fine on my machine - I can open 10 clients and they all can chat with each other.

However, if I log into another network and open 10 clients on THAT machine, they too can all chat with each other, but.... the clients on the other network cannot chat with the clients on my machine - even though they are all sharing the same server!!

It's as though they end up on different meshes or something like that.  They are all running the same code and exact same app.config files, pointing to the same server instance, but the server is not passing the information all the way around.

What am I doing wrong here?  There are no error messages, just separate "groups" that cant' inter-communicate.

Thanks.